# Quota limitation Page Speed V5

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed

Currently while parsing through API of Page Speed V5, there is a quota limitation.
whenever the file has URLs over 100.
We currently don't know what is the quota limitations per day or per user or per time bound.

Can we have the details of quota limitation?

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/reference/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed#try-it
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google imposes a quota limit on PageSpeed Insights API usage. The current limit (as of September, 2015) is 25,000 requests / day and 1 requests / second. The default pause is 1 second between sending requests to Google to avoid exceeding quota.

For more information you can refer the following URL.

https://nodepit.com/node/com.mmiagency.knime.nodes.google.pagespeed.GooglePageSpeedNodeFactory